# What is the type of an object literal key as defined in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, enums, typescript, webstorm, object-literal

I'm not using TypeScript as the primary language for this application, but as the type-hinting assist for JetBrains' WebStorm alongside JSDocs. I'm also using the [keyMirror](https://github.com/STRML/keyMirror) utility to create quasi-enum object literals.

Given the following:

```
//enums.js
var keyMirror = require('keyMirror');
module.exports = {
    CRUDVerbs: keyMirror({ //keymirror mirrors the key to value in objects
        CREATE: null,
        READ: null,
        UPDATE: null,
        DESTROY: null
    }
}

//app.js
var enums = require('enums.js');
var CrudTypes = enums.CRUDVerbs;
/** @type {??????????} **/
var returnedVal = functionFromElsewhere();
if(returnedVal === CrudTypes.CREATE) {
//code
} //..etc...
```

What is the type of `returnedVal` and of `CrudTypes.CREATE`, for the purposes of defining it in e.g. `enums.d.ts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The code](https://github.com/STRML/keyMirror/blob/master/index.js) for keyMirror assigns the property key to the value:

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        ret[key] = key;
    }
}
```

Therefore, the type of `returnVal` and `CrudTypes.CREATE` should be `string`.

Note that `Object.keys(...)` returns `string[]` in TypeScript and that the following code outputs `string` for all the keys:

```
var obj = { 1: null, "2": null };
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(typeof key);
}
```

Comment: Much obliged. I thought so, but wasn't sure - I came from strictly-typed C & C-like languages, so I've had a bit of trouble mentally keeping track of things.